# R longitudinal data time period

Tags: r

I have some trouble in getting the "wave" column. Currently we only know the first two columns.How could I write the code to get the third column? I really appreciate your help!

```
user_id        week         wave
001              1            1
001              2            2
001              4            4
002              2            1
002              3            2
002              5            4
003              4            1
003              7            4
004              5            1
004              6            2
```

Comment: Well, you should probably define the rule that gives the value for the wave column. It is unclear from your sample date.

Comment: Thanks! The rule is that if a user(i.e.user 001) posted in week 1 for the first time, the corresponding wave value is 1. If user 001 posted in week 2 for the 2nd time, the corresponding wave value is 2. If a user (i.e. user 003) posted in week 4 for the first time, the corresponding wave value is 1. User 003 posted in week 7 for the 2nd time, the corresponding wave value is 4.

Comment: It's best to edit your original question to include these important details rather than adding the info in the comments. Also, changing your expected data is a big change so be careful when posting the original question, otherwise you are wasting the time of others that attempt to re-create your invalid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updates from the comments and the update data, you could do (assuming your data is stored in a data.frame called `dd`)

```
dd$wave <- with(dd, ave(week, user_id, FUN=function(x) {x-min(x)+1}))
```

Here we use `ave` to look at each user separately, then we take the different from the first week they have a value to every other to calculate the wave value. This results in

```
   user_id week wave
1        1    1    1
2        1    2    2
3        1    4    4
4        2    2    1
5        2    3    2
6        2    5    4
7        3    4    1
8        3    7    4
9        4    5    1
10       4    6    2
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

For the old dataset, if `dat` is the dataset.

```
with(dat, ave(week, user_id, FUN=function(x) {
        if(!any(diff(x)>1)) NA else x-(x[1]-1)}))
#[1]  1  2  4  1  2  4  1  4 NA NA
```

#### Update

Using new dataset, if you want to use other options

```
 library(dplyr)
 dat%>% group_by(user_id)%>% mutate(wave=week-week[1]+1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The rule is that if a user(i.e.user 001) posted in week 1 for the first time, the corresponding wave value is 1. If user 001 posted in week 2 for the 2nd time, the corresponding wave value is 2. If a user (i.e. user 003) posted in week 4 for the first time, the corresponding wave value is 1. User 003 posted in week 7 for the 2nd time, the corresponding wave value is 4.

Comment: @user3798096.  The updated dataset is different than you posted.  You already got the answer from Mr. Flick.